# upgrade ubuntu 19.10 but still kernel 5.0.0-31-generic

Tags: kernel, 19.10

i have upgraded Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 but kernel showing Linux 5.0.0-31-generic . is this right kernel?

Comment: Lets take a look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/kernel/linux-image-generic and it seems `linux-image-5.3.0-19-generic` up to date. Sometimes the kernel can't be updated, when `/boot/`is full. Please check `ls -l /boot/` if you need to clean up to make space for an upgrade.

Comment: output of   ls -l /boot/        last four line                                                                                       
   -rw------- 1 root root  8785656 Oct  1 00:08 vmlinuz-5.0.0-31-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 11361152 Sep 16 04:08 vmlinuz-5.3.0-050300-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 11391736 Oct 18 13:48 vmlinuz-5.3.0-19-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 11395832 Oct 23 12:16 vmlinuz-5.3.0-20-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 Nov 12 10:55 vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-5.3.0-20-generic

Comment: So, we can see 5.**3**.0.20 is installed. Is /boot/ an extra partition on your system? Than `df - h` would be the next step, to check if there is enough space available. If you've got trouble with 5.3.0.**20**, remove it. May you just want to try your luck and try `apt install linux-image-5.3.0-19-generic` and see what will happen. The system will tell you in detail what is wrong.

Comment: Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev

Comment: rakesh1812@rakesh1812-Inspiron-15-3567:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           785M  1.9M  783M   1% /run
/dev/sda3       898G  179G  674G  21% /
tmpfs           3.9G   55M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       596M   34M  563M   6% /boot/efi

Comment: Please try to focus on the important information. If the question is 'how much space is on /boot/, it isn't important how much space is on /dev, /run or / ... `df -h |grep -i boot` ... And no information if `apt install linux-image-5.3.0-19-generic` works or tell anything what is going wrong on your system.

Comment: df -h |grep -i boot
/dev/sda1       596M   34M  563M   6% /boot/efi

Comment: Yeah, /boot/efi is not the place where the kernel is ... So /boot should be in / and I hope there is enough space available.

Comment: 8 gb ram 1 Tb hard disk

Answer (score 2):

linux-generic 5.0.0.31 is the kernel for 19.04 and you are using 19.10 which currently has linux-generic 5.3.0.21.24. Unless Canonical Livepatch Service is enabled, after the kernel is updated it is used for the first time the next time Ubuntu reboots or cold starts. Since there are limitations to the kernel livepatch technology, some Linux kernel code paths cannot be safely patched while running. There may be occasions when the traditional kernel upgrade and reboot might still be necessary.

If you keep the working 5.0.0.31 kernel and wait a few weeks the boot problem will probably be solved by a kernel update. Until then you have a working kernel, a bootable system and time to wait to see if the problem will go away by itself.

You can mark the kernels you want as `hold` or `unhold` using `apt-mark`.

```
sudo apt-mark hold kernel-version
```

From `man apt-mark`:

```
hold
    hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the
    package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.

unhold
    unhold is used to cancel a previously set hold on a package to
    allow all actions again.
```

After you unhold linux-generic you can upgrade it with the following command:

```
sudo apt upgrade linux-generic
```

Comment: in advance option , when i used 5.3.0.19/20 my screen  freeze with purple color but  5.0.0.31 is working

Answer (score 0):

To answer the Question: No, it is an old Kernel.
As @karel pointed out, it is the Ubuntu 19.04 kernel.

There are various reasons why the kernel isn't upgraded.

## No disc space in /boot/

In some setups /boot/ is an own partition, seen with `mount |grep -i boot`. If there is enough space available, you can use `df -h |grep boot` ...
In your case, only **/boot/efi** is seen, so **/boot/** is a path in **/** and **/** should have enough space at an 1TB drive.
We are pretty sure at a dead end at this analysis in the comments.

## Something else went wrong during the installation

**apt**, the frontend of the packagemanager **dpkg** is very intelligent and does not stupid install a kernel and hopes everything went fine. There are plenty of checks in the preinstallation scripts and postinstallation scripts. And in most cases a clean rollback to the last good state.
To see what went wrong, we should analyze the process, by opening a console/terminal/tty/... and enter `apt install linux-image-5.3.0-19-generic` (seen at https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/kernel/linux-image-generic as the latest amd64 Kernel) ... Maybe `apt install linux-image-generic` will do the trick as well, but since it is a metapackage without own content, I wouldn't risk it.
The output will lead us to the next question, based of the reason, why the package isn't installed. I've seen wrong hashcodes (caused by malware scanner/proxy), running out of space on disk, missing decencies caused by an outdated PPA ... There are plenty of possible reasons. Maybe the package is just on hold, as @karel already described. Before unhold you should take a look why it is on hold.

Comment: rak r commented under my answer In GRUB menu -> Advanced options for Ubuntu, when I selected the 5.3.0.19/20 kernel my screen froze with purple color from which I gathered that 5.3.0.19 and 5.3.0.20 kernels are installed in Ubuntu 19.10, but it's not possible to boot from either kernel. So rak is booting Ubuntu 19.10 from an older kernel instead.

Comment: Ah, okay. I've overread this. Thanks for the point.

Answer (score 0):

If the 5.3 kernel is in /boot there may be a simple explanation: the /vmlinuz and /initrd.img links are no longer updated and if /etc/grub.d/ contains a default entry using /vmlinuz then the 5.0 kernel will boot. In 19.04 the links were updated, but in 19.10 this stopped.